# How do get human-readable function definition from ABI in Python?

Tags: python, abi

By human-readable I mean how the definition looks like in solidity. [Example](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/formats/). Wasn't able to find it in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Not python, but https://github.com/gnidan/abi-to-sol. No idea if a similar tool exists in python, but if it doesn't, this should give you leads on how to make one